# Printing % characters with printf function in perl

Tags: perl, printing, printf

I have a Perl script that takes as an input a text file containing several sentences (`Sentences.txt`). Each sentence is separated with a white line. The script creates separate text files for each sentence in `Sentences.txt`. For example, `Sent1.txt` for the first sentence in `Sentences.txt`, `Sent2.txt` for the second sentence in `Sentences.txt` and so on.

The problem comes when I try to print a sentence from `Sentences.txt` to the corresponding separate file (`SentX.txt`) using the `printf` function and the sentence contains a `%` character. How can I solve this?

This is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

# Separate sentences
my $sep_dir = "./sep_dir";

# Sentences.txt
my $sent = "Sentences.txt";
open my $fsent, "<", $sent or die "can not open '$sent'\n";

# read sentences
my $kont = 1;
my $previous2_line = "";
my $previous_line = "";
my $mom_line = "";
while(my $line = <$fsent>){
    chomp($line);
    #
    $previous2_line = $previous_line;
    #
    $previous_line = $mom_line;
    #
    $mom_line = $line;
    if($mom_line !~ m/^\s*$/){
        # create separate sentence file
        my $fitx_esal = "Sent.$kont.txt";
        open my $fesal, ">", $fitx_esal or die "can not open '$fitx_esal'\n";
        printf $fesal $mom_line;
        close $fesal or die "can not close '$fitx_esal'.\n";
        $kont++;
    }
}
close $fsent or die "can not close '$sent'.\n";
```

Comment: are you sure you need to use `printf` here? maybe use `print`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to put the sentence as you found it, why not use `print`? That has no Problem with %.

If `printf` is required you will need to replace every % with %%, for example using

```
$sentence =~ s/%/%%/g;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `f` in `printf` stands for "format", not "file". You're missing the format parameter.

```
printf $fesal "%s", $mom_line;
```

But you could simply use

```
print $fesal $mom_line;
```

To include `%` in a `(s)printf` format, double it: `%%`.